# Algorithm in increasing order - O(tlgn)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, pseudocode

Suppose a given set 'A1, A2, ... An' increasing number of vectors. Let's say that each 'Ai' has 'Ti' elements. We want to print all 't = t1 + t2 + t3 + ... + tn' numbers in ascending order. Give an algorithm that consumes time 'O(tlgn)' to do the job.
Example:
A1 = 2,5,0,20,30 -> T1 = 5 
A2 = 30,5,8 -> T2 = 3
A3 = 8,1,3,10,5 -> T3 = 5
n = 3 (number of arrays) and T = 13 (total numbers of elements)
Result: 0,1,2,3,5,5,5,8,8,10,20,30,30 in 0(tlgn) where lg n = log2(n)

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: I was thinking in to use minHeap and get A[1] of every array 't' times in each array too, but it doesn't work in O(tlgn). I tried to use queue priority but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Would you describe the task in more detail?I dont see, for example, where you do sums? Your output appears to be just all the numbers sorted. What is the meaning of "increasing number of vectors"? Neither the number of elements nor the elements itself are increasing.

Comment: You are right. The goal is only to sort in ascending order 'n' arrays with 't' elements in time O(tlgn), where t = all elements count and n = number of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

A general strategy would be to combine the arrays into one array (O(N)). Then perform a sort of some variety: [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort) is O(n lg(n)) in the worst case. This assumes there are no restrictions on memory usage.